# Regex validation for email with specific condition

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Currently I am using below code to validate email

```
public static bool IsValidEmail(string email)
        {
            var r = new Regex(@"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-\.\'\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$");
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) && r.IsMatch(email);
        }
```

Now want to validate this "abc@a.bb.com" email as valid email id. what change needs to be done in regex?

Comment: Don't use a regex? Even https://emailregex.com/ is wrong some of the time. You could use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddress.trycreate?view=net-5.0 instead.

Comment: @jeremy thanks for the reply, I am looking required change/edit in my Regex to accept "abc@a.bb.com"

Comment: `([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+` That's only matching sub-domains that start and end with an alphanumeric, and therefore must have 2 characters. But I still wouldn't try to "fix" the regex, because a regex is *never* going to be 100% right. Stop trying to use a hammer for everything, use the right tool. If you want to check if an email is valid, try to send a verification code.

Answer (score 3):

Using this Regex is not the best way to validate an Email.

But, correcting your Regex to the pattern you asked, it would be like this:

```
var r = new Regex(@"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-\.\'\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z\.])+[.a-zA-Z]{2,9})$");
```

Still insisting on the regex, you can find a more complete pattern in: https://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

I encourage you to use Microsoft documentation for email address as suggested by @Jeremy Lakeman -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddress.trycreate?view=net-5.0